# Force surrounding div to enclose elements

Tags: html, css

I have a container div which should alter to wrap around it's contents producing a bordered effect however for some reason the div seems to just appear as a line at the top of the page. The image below show what I would like to acheive but as you can see from this  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/9yUX3/)  it's not working.

Any suggestions?

```
Code enclosed in Fiddle.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the contents of the div are floated left and the div isn't. Apply `float: left;` to the div with the border and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/9yUX3/7/

Comment: Cheers. Any pointers as to how to achieve the shadowy border effect?

Comment: CSS3 box shadow: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp (dont kill me for a w3schools link)

Comment: Another quirky trick I've found is that if the hight of the container is set to `auto` and you apply `overflow: hidden;` it will stretch the parent container to the required size rather than hiding the child.

Comment: @Andy providing a link is all well and good but I had already got that far as you will see from the fiddle. Please could you amend the fiddle and provide an example.

Comment: try `margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 20px; box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 0px #888;` on `.boxed_content` the margin top/bottom is important because of your overflow hidden and other positioning

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix this problem is to apply overflow:hidden (or auto) to the .boxed_content DIV. This may be better for you as applying a  float to the container may mess up your layout further down the line.

```
.boxed_content {
   border: 1px solid black;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #c4c4c4;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the ways to contain floats http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/contain-floats.php